# Grouping items in an array?

Tags: sorting, algorithm

Hey guys, if I have an array that looks like [A,B,C,A,B,C,A,C,B] (random order), and I wish to arrange it into [A,A,A,B,B,B,C,C,C] (each group is together), and the only operations allowed are:
1)query the i-th item of the array
2)swap two items in the array.

How to design an algorithm that does the job in O(n)?

Thanks!

Comment: If this is homework then please tag as such.

Comment: Please tag this as homework. Are the ranges of values 9A, B, C, etc. restricted?)

Comment: there are n items, but restricted number of categories (say 3 for example).
O(n) time. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sort algorithms aren't something you design fresh (i.e. first step of your development process) anymore; you should research known [sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) [algorithms](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/) and see what meets your needs.

(It is of course possible you might really require your own new sort algorithm, but usually that has different—and highly-specific—[requirements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort).)

If this isn't your first step (but I don't think that's the case), it would be helpful to know what you've already tried and how it failed you.

Comment: This is related to sorting, but not a sorting problem.  He wants an O(n) algorithm to group items together in the array - the order of the groups doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually just [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

Scan the array once, count the number of As, Bs, Cs—that should give you an idea. This becomes like [bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort)—not quite but along those lines. The count of As Bs and Cs should give you an idea about where the string of As, Bs and Cs belongs.

Comment: Did you know you can use `[text](URL)`? It's curious for someone that commented encouraging tagging as homework to just give away the answer. (That last has nothing to do with you, even though I have been critical of your blatant rep-whoring lately, just my recent notice of the homework tag and how it's applied.)

Comment: No P. However, beware that you are asked to work this thing in-place. So, it is a bit different I think.

Comment: Roger, I wrote in this forum that I am not going to get laid by my gf until I get 1000 rep. You aren't that gullible, are you. Also, about hw: I know plenty of people who took algorithms to never see that stuff again and code awesome php web pages. Trust me when I say that these guys will not need to implement their own sort ... ever.

Comment: And by the way, I did take an OS class but I do not remember 80% of what I studied there. I did mostly my own work. I will admit that my undergrad program was not the best.

Comment: I honestly don't care *why* you said you need 1k rep (and I never saw that specific comment, only http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995815/), but I've seen you abusing the system (unfortunately the deleted question was the best example) and that behavior should be discouraged.

Comment: I was honestly trying to help you format better answers (and thus get the rep you desperately need *without* abusing the system).  I find the `[text](URL)` format easiest to type instead of using the UI buttons (and rarely use the other link formats).  Edited to show example.

Comment: Ah, now I understand your OS class comment.  I was just talking publicly about homework tagging/commenting, as I've been paying closer attention (instead of just ignoring the debate as I did previously).  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34503/ and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34511/ for reference.